# How to keep Entity Framework and database aligned

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

in early development stages the database is subject to continuous changes. I'm toying around with LinqToSQL and in most cases the Entity Model is just a 1:1 representation of the DB.

How can i keep the model up to date with the db changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that there is an "update model from database" command available if you right-click the Entity Framework design surface. I couldn't find such a thing for LINQ to SQL, so you might have to maintain by hand.

OTOH, it's just XML, so you could "just write some code".

---

The other thing to add is that I prefer the fact that in EF, I don't *have to* keep up to date with the physical database. I'm defining the entities that developers will use to access the data, and separately I'm defining the mapping between those entities and the logical database structure.

They don't need to be the same. If I want to split a table into two, or combine two entities into one table, I can do this, without requiring developers to rewrite their code.